# OpenLayers 4.6.5 blurs image with raster source

Tags: openlayers

It is observed that when i use imaeStatic as a source to image layer then image does not blur but when i use Raster then it does.

```
// Image Static
const imageSource = new ImageStatic({
      projection: this.projection,
      imageExtent: this.extent,
      imageSize: [imageWidth, imageHeight],
      url: imageURL,
      crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
    })

// Setting source to image layer
imageLayer.setSource(imageSource);
```

[image: Image without blur]

Now,
If i add a raster Source, same image becomes bit bulry.

```
// Image Static
const imageSource = new ImageStatic({
      projection: this.projection,
      imageExtent: this.extent,
      imageSize: [imageWidth, imageHeight],
      url: imageURL,
      crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
    })

// Raster
const raster = new Raster({
      sources: [imageSource],
      operation: (pixels, data) => {
        // (Brightness and contrast operation)
        return response;
      },
      lib: {
        truncateColor: truncateColor,
        getBrightness: getBrightness,
        getContrast: getContrast
      }
    });

// Setting raster source
imageLayer.setSource(raster);
```

[image: Image with blur]

I am not able to understand this behaviour and not sure how it can be fixed.
Any suggestions?

Note : After adding a raster source, even if i don't make changes in pixel, it still loads blur image.

Comment: If you can only use version 4.6.5 there seems to be no options available.  If you can use version 5 or 6 you might get some improvement by using a layer instead of source and disabling image smoothing in the precompose event (OL5) or prerender event (OL6) as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/sea-level.html, or better still (v6.4.3 onwards) by disabling image smoothing in the source options https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html

Comment: Hi @Mike.
Thank you for response. I could actually use image smoothing with 4.6.5 version and i could see slight improvement as well, not much though.
I used below snippet. But still i think this is something related to ratio or width which i need to look into.

Code snippet : 
imageLayer.on('prerender', function (evt) {
      evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    });

Comment: The image will be stretched to fit the extent if necessary (which will break any attempt as disabling smoothing unless you use OL6).  Make sure the extent exactly matches the physical image size for best results.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. Same extent is being used for ImageStatic as well as Raster but, in case of raster i could see blur effect. So does that mean in case of raster usage, extent is getting changed?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use `imageSmoothingEnabled` directly with 4.6.5 version. To address this issue, I created a one more Image layer for raster source.
Now when i want to make use of image pixels, then i used to set visibility of raster source.

```
const imageLayer = new ImageLayer({})
imageLayer.setSource(ImageStaticSource);

const rasterImageLayer = new ImageLayer({})
rasterImageLayer.setSource(RasterSource);

if(need image pixels) {
   rasterImageLayer.setVisible(true);
   imageLayer.setVisible(false);
}
else {
   rasterImageLayer.setVisible(false);
   imageLayer.setVisible(true);
}
```